# GWT: some functionality stop working in internationalization

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I have a small GWT application ,which have internationalization,
 everything's running fine if i run in default mode , but if i change some language for example to french etc..

some functionality stop working ..Not getting any erros..but things are not working as expected and as they are in default language

I try to debug the application , but its not stopping  at any breakpoint ,whereas if i debug in default language it stops on the breakpoints perfectly ..

Any idea whats the reason .

thanks

Comment: How do you "change the language" of your app? Are you preserving the `gwt.codesvr=` query-string parameter?

Comment: i have the appconstants of all languages and in appname.gwt.xml , i have this ::  <extend-property name="locale" values="fr,gm,sp"/> :: and this one to change the language : Anchor french=new Anchor("French",GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"?locale=fr");

Comment: u right, gwt.codesvr not preserving , when i switch to a language , i have this in my browser's url : http://127.0.0.1:8888/?locale=fr#main::  nothing else, whats the correct way of doing it

Comment: GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() returns something like "http://127.0.0.1:8888/" in development mode, so you loose the gwt.codesrv parameter, which is needed for debugging. you have to make it to "http://127.0.0.1:8888/page.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=fr" - use GWT.isProdMode() to distinct between devmode and production mode, or just call the URL directly to debug. that said, what features don't work? which GWT classes are involved?

Comment: …so you're losing the `gwt.codesvr=` and thus leaving DevMode; so it's no surprise that it doesn't stop on breakpoints. BTW, I don't think `gm` and `sp` are valid locales. http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47

Comment: Have a look at [`Window.Location.createUrlBuilder()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#createUrlBuilder%28%29)

Comment: @MarioP    one example which is not working is, there is a point when i need to make some rpc by clicking on some word which is in french . and the RPC doesnt make , but if i am in default language and the same word is in englishm rpc called fine

Comment: @junaidp - this might be a side effect of being out of development mode. is it still broken when you call the french url directly, without clicking the anchor?

Comment: i just tried , changing the url directly like this :http://127.0.0.1:8888/DashBoardSupervisor.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997/?locale=fr#main:, in this case its working fine , going in debug , and also expected functionality is working fine now ..thanks ... I'm trying to make the correct URL with the click of the anchor

Comment: @Thomas Broyer, Window.Location.createUrlBuilder(), really helped , Thanks

Comment: is adding Internationalization in UiBinder is a small task? ;like in my view class i'm doing this : myLabelName =new Label(constants.EXAMPLENAME());, is it as simple in Uibinder  , or we need to do some work around

Comment: don't have any experience using it, but the GWT docs have a whole page devoted to i18n combined with UIBinder: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n - glancing over it, it seems to be the same concept as the "normal" i18n approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone experiences the same problem and stumbles upon this question, a small summary of the comments:

The problem was caused by dropping out of development mode when changing the language, because the resulting URL looked like `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?locale=fr` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&locale=fr` (notice the gwt.codesvr parameter, a vital part of development mode)